# How to combine all js files?

Tags: javascript, css

I have more than javascript files in my html documents as external which I'd like to combine on account of not to be crowded. is there any way to combine my js files ? for example;

my files:

```
a.js
b.js
c.js
d.js
```

and i want;

```
all.js
```

Comment: Take a look at Grunt.js

Comment: Just Copy & Paste? On my Mac I use CodeKit for that.

Comment: simply include all your scripts in your all.js

Comment: @yedincifirat do the different files depend on each other? If they do are you just dumping dependencies into the global name space? If you are you should avoid doing that as it can cause hard to find bugs.  I'd recommend using http://rollupjs.org/ and the `export xyz;` and `import {bar} from './some/bar_script.js';` syntax for exporting and importing dependencies.  The other tools mentioned here like gulp, grunt, requirejs, r.js, browserify, etc are all good options which do some very different things so you'll need to research more when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at requirejs.org and especially look at r.js (http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html)

Answer (score 0):

a.js

```
var i=0;
function fun1()
{
...
}
```

b.js

```
var k=0;
function fun2()
{
...
}
```

all.js just copy, paste like **css**

```
var i=0;
function fun1()
{
...
}
var k=0;
function fun2()
{
...
}
```

take care of semicolons and closed braces when you purticularly write whole script in an `eventlistener`, especially `'DOMContentLoaded'`

```
document.addEventlistener('DOMContentloaed',function()
{

//whole big script

}
);
```

***instead*** use

```
document.addEventlistener('DOMContentloaed',some_function);

var some_function = function(){*bla bla bla*};
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple bash `cat` operation will do what you want, but, at some stage you're probably going to want more right?

[Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and [Grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) is a good starter, but you'll quickly realise grunt is not particularly good. To summarise usage, you create a `gruntfile`, install a few dependencies (i.e. install `grunt` and its command line interface, this is easy) and run `grunt` from your project root. It then parses the gruntfile to find out what you want it to do, and it does it. Pretty simple, and simple is good.

Next up is [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), which is a nice build system using streams, so, slightly more complex (well, easier and more powerful but, streams can be kind-of confusing at first). Gulp works in the same way only it parses a `gulpfile` for instructions. For a concat operation the actual gulp command is trivial:

```
gulp.src( '*.js' )
  .pipe( gulp.dest( 'all.js' )
```

Between the `.src` and the `.dest` you can pipe the files through multiple transforms, such as minifying, transpiling, notifying—the list of plugins and modules is dizzying (as it is for grunt).

However, if you’re a fan of node and npm (you probably should be) then you can use `npm scripts` to create a build system. `npm` is the node package manager and requires a `package.json` to give some clues as to how to work. Part of that json specification is a `scripts` block

```
"scripts": {
  "build" : "cat *.js > all.js"
}
```

You can then use `npm run build` from the command line, whereby `npm` will parse the `package.json` and execute the script using bash (sh actually).

*Note that these are build systems, and there are many others.*

There are also other packagers (which you would probably use as part of your build system, although for some projects they **are** you entire build system) but they are more complex than your needs, for your own research [browserify](http://browserify.org/), [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) and [jspm](http://jspm.io/) are all excellent (bare in mind AMD modules lost so [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) is probably not worth your time), although this area is becoming congested. Each of these are very powerful modularisation tools, but they will require some changes to how you structure your code. If you are serious about modularisation then they are worth your time learning.

*On a slightly different tangent, there is some discussion about whether one large file is actually more beneficial than a number of smaller scripts. In many cases simply serving a few small files is actually quicker, and may be easier, although there can be other benefits of smashing code together. Currently it is probably still best to concat at least into less HTTP requests, but this requirement for performance is going away.*

Answer (score -1):

It might be helpful : https://github.com/mrclay/minify

OR

create file all.js and paste a.js,b.js,c.js,d.js file code